# Angular 2: Add "See More" in Search Suggestion

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ngfor

How do you add a "See More" link if data reaches minimum of 8? How will you append it in `*ngFor`? Is there other way?

Below is my existing code in the html

```
<div class="suggestion" *ngIf="results.length > 0 && suggest === true">
        <div *ngIf="results.length < 9; else seeMore">
             <div *ngFor="let result of results" class="search-res" > {{result.name}} </div>
        </div>
        <div #seeMore> See More </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But as you did, when results are more than 9 you don't show the initial 9, only the See More text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `<div #seeMore> See More </div>` to

```
<ng-template #seeMore>
  <div>See More</div>
</ng-template>
```

To keep only the first 8 results and then append the see more link just correct your `ngFor` with

```
*ngFor="let result of results.slice(1,9)"
```

So you'll print only the initial results. You'll probably want to update the ending number `9` of the `slice` method programmatically after each `see more` click.

Comment: I want "See More" to be appended after the 8th item @crash